# how to fire StoryBoard on window loaded event (code behind)?

Tags: wpf

I have a window with StoryBoard that stored in Window's resource as follows:

```
<Storyboard  x:Key="FadeInStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GridNotificationWindow" From="0.01" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GridNotificationWindow" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2" BeginTime="0:0:6"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

And in code behind as follows:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard s = (Storyboard)this.TryFindResource("FadeInStoryBoard");
        if(s!=null)
        {
            BeginStoryboard(s);
        }
    }
```

But it seems that is not working...
If i set it in xaml, it's working:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded" SourceName="GridNotificationWindow">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FadeInStoryBoard" >
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GridNotificationWindow" From="0.01" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GridNotificationWindow" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2" BeginTime="0:0:6"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
```

How to can i fix for code behind?

Comment: Try `s.Begin()` in place of `BeginStoryboard(s);`

Comment: i tryied it, but it's not working:/ i tried also s.Begin(this); but still not working..

Comment: Works fine at my end with `s.Begin()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the target before calling **BeginStoryboard**

```
  Storyboard.SetTarget(s, TargetName);
```